# Получение координат Label с массива, в который Label помещён

Tags: массивы, wpf, canvas

Поле состоит из клеток:

```
class IDrawer
{
    public static Cell[,] Board { get; private set; } = new Cell[8, 8]; // Массив из клеток, размера 8 на 8, как само поле

    private void TakeBoard() // Метод получения самой доски (заполнение)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                Board[i, j] = new Cell(i, j); // Каждый элемент массива является клеткой (имеет все поля класса Cell)
            }
        }
    }
    public IDrawer()
    {
        TakeBoard();
    }
}
public class Cell // Создаём клетку (ячейку) доски
{
    public bool isClicked { get; set; } // Параметр для выделения
    private bool isFilled { get; set; } // Параметр окрашивания

    public Label Square { get; private set; } // Контрол для самой клетки
    
    public Cell(int i, int j)
    {
        isFilled = j % 2 == 0 ? i % 2 == 0 : i % 2 != 0; // Формула покраски клеток
        new Placement();
        Square = new Label // Инициализируем клетку, задаём размер, красим
        {
            Width = 75,
            Height = 75,
            Background = isFilled ? Brushes.RosyBrown : Brushes.White,
            Content = Placement.field[i,j],
            FontSize = 20
        };
    }
}
```

Помещено на Canvas так:

```
private void field_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) // Создаём обработчик события для Canvas, чтобы отрисовать доску.
    {
        field.Children.Clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                field.Children.Add(IDrawer.Board[i, j].Square); // Дoбавляем на Canvas элементы массива с клетками (уже закрашенными и с установленным размером для каждой).
                Canvas.SetTop(IDrawer.Board[i, j].Square, 75 * i); // Устанавливаем позицию на Canvas.
                Canvas.SetLeft(IDrawer.Board[i, j].Square, 75 * j);
                IDrawer.Board[i, j].Square.MouseLeftButtonUp += field_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Возник вопрос, как сделать выделение клетки при клике на неё. Мой вариант был таким, и сначала казался идеально рабочим:

```
if(sender is Label label) label.Background.Red;
```

Но он некорректен, т.к дальше потребуется по двум кликам менять местами Label'ы. Соответственно, нужно выбирать по клику Label, и получать координаты Label с массива, чтобы местоположение в массиве, соответственно, менять.
Как реализовать получение координат Label на массиве, при клике?

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужно добавить метод обработчика Click для Label при инициализации клетки. Оттуда можно будет выцепить и координаты через свойство Content.

Comment: Если принципиально использование Canvas, то можно модифицировать класс Cell, добавив в него поля(или свойства), описывающие координаты ячейки, данные которых будут записываться при отрисовке canvas.